# Accept=".xls" not working in firefox and ie in HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to open the **File Reference** window to **upload** .xls file.  So i try to filter the file by setting  '.xls' in **accept** attribute.

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" size="50" accept=".xls">
```

It is filtering fine in **GoogleChrome**.

[image]

But in **Firefox** and **Ie**, it is not filtering.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" size="50" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" >
```

set mimeType and it works

Comment: In FireFox, All files(*.*) and Microsoft Excel(97-2003) WorkSheet (*.xls) listed in combobox. But, by default All files(*.*) value is selected. I need Microsoft Excel(97-2003) WorkSheet (*.xls) to selected as default.

Comment: i think you don't fix it, i find documentation on BugZilla (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826176) and for mozilla developer is correctly that you can see All Files(*.*)

Comment: Technically, the `accept` attribute value in the answer specifies both .xls and .xlsx files, which may well be better than just .xls, but the questions asks for .xls (and it is imaginable that in some context, .xls can be accepted but .xlsx cannot). To specify just .xls, you would you use `accept="application/vnd.ms-excel"`.